# Java - While loop where all conditions must be false for it to exit

Tags: java

First of all is this possible? Second of all if it is how can it be done? Im trying to get the following code to work like that but even if one of the variables is 0 it exits the loop, it needs to be made that all 3 variables are less than 1 for it to exit

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BabyNim
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a, b, c, input;
        String pile;

        a = 3;
        b = 3;
        c = 3;

        System.out.println("A: " + a + "\tB: " + b + "\tC: " + c);

        while (a > 1 && b > 1 && c > 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Pile: ");
            pile = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("How many to remove: ");
            input = keyboard.nextInt();

            switch (pile) {
                case "a": {
                    a = a - input;
                }case "b": {
                    b = b - input;
                }case "c": {
                    c = c - input;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (a >= 1 || b >= 1 || c >= 1)
```

Comment: Add `break` statements at the end of each of your switch cases so it doesn't fall through to the following case.

Comment: Although it only exits if you subtract from a, b and c do not cause it to exit

Comment: son of a... I just started using switch/case, thanks for that, it works now

Answer (score 1):

> it needs to be made that all 3 variables are less than 1 for it to exit

Like that, this is what is needed so that it exits, right?

```
a < 1 && b < 1 && c < 1
```

So, negate it:

```
!(a < 1 && b < 1 && c < 1)
```

Which can be written like this:

```
a >= 1 || b >= 1 || c >= 1
```

As others posted, you had a problem on your `switch` block that hadn't a `break;` after each condition. At least if that wasn't the intention.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be your switch: statement. If I remember correctly you need to put a 'break;' at the end of each case statement, otherwise you run the possibility of "falling through" other case criteria.

Also you have to examine the order of operations when using a boolean for a conditional. `while( a > 1 && b > 1 && c > 1)` will short circuit to false when `a < 1`. you may be looking for a mix of your condition and the one offered by @Andy Turner:

```
while(a>=1 && b>=1 && c >=1)
```